# nginx for ubuntu open-source stream access_log not allowed

Tags: nginx, stream, access-log

We have run nginx open source on windows using stream access_log successfully.

When we try to run nginx open source on ubuntu using stream access_log, it is not allowed.

Is there a way to enable stream server access_log in nginx open source on ubuntu?

Comment: Show config and nginx version

Comment: stream server access_log fails on:

nginx version: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

Comment: stream server access_log works on:
nginx version: nginx/1.11.5 (nginx-plus-r11)

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

Comment: stream {
 ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/nginx/x.com.crt; #public
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx/x.com.key; #private
 ssl_protocols         SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
 ssl_ciphers           HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
 ssl_session_timeout   1h;
 ssl_handshake_timeout 30s;
 log_format main '$remote_addr $time_iso8601 '
 '$protocol status $bytes_sent $bytes_received '
 '$session_time '
 '$upstream_bytes_sent $upstream_bytes_received $upstream_connect_time';

   upstream YTA {server 127.0.0.1:21960;}
   server {listen 21966 ssl; proxy_pass YTA; access_log /var/logs/YTA.log main; } 
}

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_log_module.html was introduced in version 1.11.4

Comment: Don't post config in comments. Edit your question. Anyway, you need newer version of nginx.

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/#ubuntu-ppa

Comment: Thanks for directing me on posting the config.

I ran the sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade, and it did not update to a newer open-source version.

Does that mean I'm on the newest open source version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138951/discussion-between-alexey-ten-and-david-ringsmuth).